# use short hash of the current git commit in a makefile

Tags: git, makefile, hash

I have the following problem:
I have a makefile that compiles a C Project and generates a .hex file.
I am using Git for the source files
Unfortunately the makefile generates an app.hex file, so I would like to add in the makefile a new clause that will generate a hex file with the name containing the short hash of the current commit that I am compiling.
I am working under Windows.
I already added the following in the Makefile:

```
tag : prebuild postbuild addtag

addtag : $(BUILD_SDIR)/$(BINARY).hex
    @echo  ----------------------------------------
    @echo   Getting Git tag
    @echo  ----------------------------------------
    @echo  GIT_TAG = call ./getGitTag.sh
    @echo  ----------------------------------------
    @echo   Adding GIT tag to hex file
    @echo  ----------------------------------------
    @echo  cp $(BUILD_DIR)\$(BINARY).hex $(BUILD_DIR)\$(BINARY)$(GIT_TAG).hex
```

with getGitTag.sh as below:

```
git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c 1-8
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I don't know why, my knowledge is quite basic so I have no idea how to debug this.
GIT TAG seems to be always empty even if the .sh script works if I am calling it
This is the output I am getting when running make tag in the cmd line:

```
----------------------------------------
  Getting Git tag
 ----------------------------------------
 GIT_TAG = call ./getGitTag.sh
 ----------------------------------------
  Adding GIT tag to hex file
 ----------------------------------------
 cp .\build\app.hex .\build\app.hex
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the first 8 characters of the hash is unique in your repository. Instead you should use `git rev-parse --short HEAD`

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "doesn't work". Does it produce an invalid hash? Does it give you an error message? What did you observe happening, and what did you expect?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen your are right about --short HEAD. about the second comment, when i run make tag in the command line I have the following output from which I draw the conclusion that GIT_TAG is empty ----------------------------------------
  Getting Git tag
 ----------------------------------------
 GIT_TAG = call ./getGitTag.sh
 ----------------------------------------
  Adding GIT tag to hex file
 ----------------------------------------
 cp .\build\app.hex .\build\app.hex

Comment: You're just echoing text to the standard output, you're not actually executing any code there.

Comment: do you mean the .sh file or the Makefile? I really have no experience with how the makefile works, that's why I asked the question

Comment: `@echo cp ...` says echo that text to screen, not run that command. Remove the `@echo` from the lines that actually need to be executed. And then follow @Vroomfondel's answer for making that work once you're actually executing the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem pops up regularly with `make`. Recipe lines are executed line by line, each in a separate shell process, which means that you can't simply instantiate shell variables and use them a few lines down, as they are disposed with the shell process immediately at line end. You have two options, #1 is to switch this feature off with the `.ONESHELL:` pseudo command - this may have ramification (if not to say problems) for parts of the makefiles which don't come from you personally - or #2: to concatenate the recipe lines with a backslash; thus the shell receives one long line of commands but this can become quite involved for complex scripts.

There is another option circumventing `make`, which is to handle everything in a true separate shell script which you call in the recipe line.

As a not so clean method one can introduce a `make` variable during recipe execution:

```
$(eval GIT_TAG := $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD))
@echo  ----------------------------------------
@echo   Git tag is: $(GIT_TAG), adding this to hex file now:
cp $(BUILD_DIR)\$(BINARY).hex $(BUILD_DIR)\$(BINARY)$(GIT_TAG).hex
@echo  ----------------------------------------
```

Consider this a workaround tho, for the obvious ad-hoc nature of the code - usually you should not split functionality in half between `make` and the shell this way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it doesn't work, this is what I get as a result:  ----------------------------------------
  Getting Git tag
 ----------------------------------------
 ----------------------------------------
  Adding GIT tag to hex file
 ----------------------------------------
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp .\build\app.hex .\build\app$(git rev-parse --short HEAD).hex, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [addtag] Error 2

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked that you are on Windows. I will rewrite it, but you must be aware that this is going to be a dirty hack, like everything which has to do with shell scripting on Windows. BTW PowerShell is not shell scripting, it is a full programming language. Unluckily it doesn't interoperate well with the text-macro-replacement approach of `make`'s recipe lines.

Comment: this works now, only cp needs to be replaced with copy I think? will this work reliably in Windows or is there some danger to it?

Comment: I think `cp` as well as `rm` were somehow aliased to the usual (or new?) Windows counterparts, but please check yourself if this is 100% true. Otherwise - it should be "reliable" as long as you don't extend functionality too much with Windows scripting - I found that the more I tried to write clever PowerShell code, the more things I broke.

Comment: I don't know if I should make a new question as this is basically is reffering to the same concept, but I would also like to be able to use the generated GIT_TAG somehow in main.c I already have in main.c 3 defines REVISION MINOR_VERSION MAJOR_VERSION, the values for these defines are written in a section from the .hex file that is generated by the makefile, my idea would be to replace these defines with the bytes from GIT_TAG so I would have in the .hex file at a specific address the commit for which it was generated. How can I make the link between GIT_TAG and these defines?

Comment: First: please rename all those references to GIT_COMMIT_HASH or something, because a git tag is something entirely different. Second: make a sanity check with `git describe --dirty` so as not to compile from a dirty repository with a commit hash which does not reflect the true status of your source tree. 3rd: yes, I think a new question (or maybe a search for an existing q in this direction) would be apt

Comment: If you have any idea how to show that the .hex file was generated from a dirty repository, that would be really useful. From my experience, I had situations where I ve built many .hex files without commiting just to try some quick fixes, in this case I would also add a time and date in  the name of the hex and some character to show if the hex was generated from a clean or a dirty repository. I will make a new question or add a comment to an existing question about generating the .h file containing the hash of the commit

Comment: @bogdan.bodnarescu use the exact syntax up there: `git describe --dirty` The string returned will have a `-dirty`at the end which can be patterned matched with one of the string functions. Or you download https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt for some additional helper functions - if you want I can sketch a string analysis with them.